# Can't center unordered list on page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

After browsing around the internet for awhile I have yet to find a way to successfully center an unordered list on my page.

Here's the HTML for the list:

```
<div id="buttons">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/tommaxwelll"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter-icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.github.com/tommaxwell"><img src="github.png" alt="github-icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/tommaxwelll"><img src="instagram.png" alt="instagram-icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/tommaxwelll"><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook-icon" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS, as recommended by other SO posts:

```
#buttons {
float: right;
position: relative;
left: -50%;
top:140px;
text-align: left;
}

#buttons ul {
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
}

#buttons li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

The float:left on list items is how I'm keeping the list horizontal. You can also view the site in question here: http://www.tommaxwell.me

Comment: i see no problem... whats wrong? give information about browser and system please. i am using chrome and the buttons are nicely centered under the text;) btw. what exactly are you trying to achieve? i have no clue what you want

Comment: what's the issue? Coz on site I am getting properly center aligned list

Comment: Do you mean that you want the surrounding container `#button` centered within the page?

Comment: If you take a close look at the unordered list, it's not centered on the page. @Ohgodwhy Yes, I want it centered because it's really bothering me that the UL is off-centered.

Comment: If you want to center the whole #button div, then you will need javascript.

Comment: Seriously? That's strange.

Comment: Why is the #buttons div it inside a table? also remove the min-width 300px on #buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following http://jsfiddle.net/QGgdR/

```
#sitecontent {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 140px auto 20px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 650px;
margin: 140px auto 0;
padding: 0 17px 4px 17px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
border: 1px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, 1);
}
#buttons {
margin: 20px auto 0;
display: block;
height: 50px;
}

#buttons ul {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
display: table;
list-style: none;
}

#buttons li {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Could I just ask what display:table does? Never used it.

Comment: Table is a display style option, it simply displays the element as a table. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into it more.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like this

```
#buttons {
display: inline;
position: relative;
right: 37px; //change this to exactly center your ul 
text-align: left;
top: 140px;
}

#buttons ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}
```

and your html

```
<center><div id="buttons">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/tommaxwelll"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter-icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.github.com/tommaxwell"><img src="github.png" alt="github-icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/tommaxwelll"><img src="instagram.png" alt="instagram-icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/tommaxwelll"><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook-icon" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center a floating list try this. Looks a bit weird but works:

```
#buttons {
    top:140px; /* your specific code */ 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons ul {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

#buttons ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: No problem, the display:table won't work in ie7 though, this one would.

Answer (score 0):

**You should try like this:**

No need to use `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;`

```
#buttons{
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[JsBin Link](http://jsbin.com/izirik/3/watch)**